# How can I get C++ to use my own custom malloc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, malloc

I'm having a memory leak issue, and would like to make my own custom malloc/new/delete/free, etc functions.  I would like to do this so that I can print a stack trace every time one of them is called, which combined with Visual Studio's heap debug tools(similar to electric fence), can be used for debugging memory leaks.

So, is there a way to tell C++ to use my own malloc?  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Thank you.

Edit: For that matter, it would be perfectly fine if malloc executed but when it did it triggered a custom function to run as well.  Somewhat wondering if _malloc_dbg could do something like that... isn't looking like it but would be nice.

Comment: Your question says C but your tag says C++.

Comment: Your question says C but your own new/delete says C++

Comment: Could you post some code so that people could better help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: "Watch" usage of "new", "delete" operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951815/c-watch-usage-of-new-delete-operators)

Comment: Thanks sashoalm, I know that linux has a few different tools that can do this... didn't find any for Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it turns out that you can call '_CrtSetAllocHook', which will allow you to set separate hooks to call a function anytime either an allocate, reallocate, or free are called.  Which is exactly what I was looking for.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/820k4tb8.aspx

Comment: I don't think you can use this on the normal CRT? It's only on a debug CRT right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a different memory allocation function, you should just call a different memory allocation function.

If you want to do that without changing your code, you can define a macro. Say you have your own allocator:

```
void *my_allocator(size_t size);
```

You can then define

```
#define malloc(x) my_allocator(x)
```

This is for malloc. In C++, you can [override the new operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/)

Comment: Please keep in mind that the #define affects only the compilation units (CU) where the #define is used, i.e. #include'd. This does not affects other CUs or libraries that has been built with the define. When you call `strdup` it will call `malloc` and you must not pass the result to your own `free` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When using the C language, just don't call `malloc`.

Call your own memory allocation functions and delete functions.

Comment: Makes it tricky if the memory leak occurs in a different library, such as strcore.cpp, which happens to be where the current leak is.

Comment: Unless you have the source code, you can't directly change the allocator that the library uses.  You *may* be able to put hooks in the run-time library or for the OS that redirects the memory allocation.  But this depends on the OS and the tools used to compile the library.